Can a Xiaomi Poco-M6-Pro sync notes from Mi-Cloud what I made on my Xiaomi Redmi 9A with all images in the notes intact?
After long discussions with my IT friend He told me about this model.
So I will replace my 9A 2GB RAM with a Poco-M6-Pro 12GB RAM 512GB Dual SIM soon.
My question is do they share the same built-in notes app and can my notes sync over from the 9A to the M6 Pro from Mi-Cloud?
